# How to minimize the calls to server to update the nodemcu pins

Tags: smart-home, esp32

I have created an api which fetchs data from sql server.
My Android app has buttons, on click it calls that api and posts status of pin.
My node mcu hit that api for the current status of the pins.
I have to call api on every second to update my devices status.
Please suggest some solution so that there are minimum calls and also have updated status.

Comment: this is a Q&A site for asking specific questions about a problem you are facing ... `Please suggest some solution` is too broad ... please focus your question to one specific problem

Comment: what is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Basically I made a smart home using nodemcu, I want my device to be controlled via internet with the current status of my devices visible on my hosted website. How can i do this.

Comment: that is not a specific question about a problem ... start experimenting and ask a question here when you face an identifiable problem